# How can I get an inset drop shadow using WPF XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've tried following a few different answers here on SO on achieving a drop shadow effect on my `Textbox`, here is the code I have so far:

```
<Style x:Key="TextBoxRoundedInset" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource TextBox.Static.Border}"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation" Value="None"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
            <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="true"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="VerticalFirst"/>
            <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                        <Border x:Name="border" CornerRadius="3" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" ClipToBounds="True">
                            <Border Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Margin="-2">
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="false" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"/>
                            <Border.Effect>
                                    <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0" BlurRadius="10"/>
                                </Border.Effect>
                            </Border>
                        </Border>

                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="border" Value="0.56"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource TextBox.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource TextBox.Focus.Border}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Property="IsInactiveSelectionHighlightEnabled" Value="true"/>
                        <Condition Property="IsSelectionActive" Value="false"/>
                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="SelectionBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                </MultiTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

Then to display with the styling I have

```
<TextBox x:Name="textBox" Background="#263238" Height="40" Margin="0,0,0,50" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="221" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" BorderThickness="0" Style="{DynamicResource TextBoxRoundedInset}" FontSize="25"/>
```

But I end up with a result that looks like this:

[image: Pic]

I don't want the text to have a glow to it, instead I basically want the text field to look like its dropped into the background any information on how to correct this would be great thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually use the `BorderThickness` Property in combination with the `BorderBrush` Property to give that 3D effect to make it look as if the field is pressed inside, or even outside by swapping the values of the `BorderThickness` of both Borders.

This is what I used with your snipped:

```
<Border x:Name="border" CornerRadius="3" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="0,0,2,2" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" ClipToBounds="True">
    <Border Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2,2,0,0" CornerRadius="2">
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="false" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"/>
    </Border>
</Border>
```

The disadvantage is not being able to change the `BorderBrush` and `BorderThickness` Property anymore since they have no Binding.

Just change the colors in those two Borders to fit your need, I usually just use Black and White since that combination usually gives the strongest effect.

Comment: Thanks this actually works quite well for now unless somebody else comes up with a different hacky way to do it. Any idea though why the text in the input field seems blurry, almost like its got its own drop shadow?

Comment: The thing with DropShadowEffect on Objects that use Text Elements is that when no Background or Fill Property is set aka "Transparent", then it also sets its value on the Content of said Text Element.

Comment: Where do I need to declare the background transparent?

Comment: You can test that behavior by slapping a <Label/> with a DropShadowEffect, leave the Background property blank and insert some text in it, then give it a Background to Red for example and see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but I did this a little differently. The effect looks less harsh, depending on chosen BorderBrush and BorderThickness.

```
<Border Background="Transparent"  BorderThickness="2"  BorderBrush="Black">
    <Border.Effect>
        <BlurEffect/>
    </Border.Effect>
    <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="false" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"/>
</Border>
```

The result can look like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tC7k0.png)